# When adding a unique IDs to your table is there any advantage to making them random?

Tags: database, oracle

Let's say I had a table with `N` rows, but no existing columns that could act as a Primary Key.

I'd like to generate one (for my convenience and completeness).

I have a few options for doing this.

1. I could use a GUID
2. I could use a sequence and generate an integer for each one (e.g., populated 1 to N)
3. I could generate a random integer
4. (and many more)

I get that GUIDs have their advantages and disadvantages.

Is there some advantage to using a randomly generated integer over a sequential integer?

Any CRUD operations on an indexed column shouldn't be affected. And if you were doing a bulk load, I would temporarily turn off the index and then restore it afterwards

I can't see a reason, but I've come across a situation (in this case Oracle) where someone has done just that and I'm hoping its more than "What's a `sequence`?".

Comment: How do you ensure uniqueness of your key when they are **random**?

Comment: true random is repeatable, how your going to avoid this ?!

Comment: The 'individual' who set up this system has set up a mechanism to check for duplicates before the new record is inserted and then re-generate the ID (as many times as necessary). Yes, there is the potential that this regeneration cycle could go one for quite some time. I didn't say I thought it was a good idea - in a 64bit integer space there seems to be a lot more collisions than one would casually expect :^).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're seeing a specific implementation that has chosen this approach, we can only speculate at what the original developer might have been thinking.  That's always subject to error.

My guess is that the original developer was trying to avoid the issue where the right-most block in the index on the sequence-generated key becomes the resource that blocks many different sessions trying to do an insert.  The "hot block" problem occurs because every session doing an `insert` needs to modify the data in the right-most block (assuming sequential keys) so Oracle needs to serialize access.  In most systems, this isn't a big deal-- the amount of serialization needed is minimal and most systems don't have enough simultaneous `insert` operations for this to be a meaningful issue.  But if you have a very high-volume system, particularly if you're running on a RAC cluster, those wait events can be meaningful.  If you had this sort of issue, generating a random key would eliminate it by causing the various sessions to (generally) write to different blocks in the index.

Of course, generating random keys would not be the recommended approach even if you found yourself waiting on the right-most block of an index frequently.  Oracle provides reverse-key indexes to take care of the hot block issue by indexing the data in reverse which distributes I/O across the blocks in the index.  If you're licensed to use the partitioning option, a hash-partitioned index would be even better.  For a more detailed discussion on [reverse-key indexes, RAC, and mitigating hot block issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9960535/good-practice-to-use-reverse-indexes-on-surrogate-keys-oracle), here's a link to a related SO question.

Comment: I imagine that this "hot block" issue would only be a concern where you were inserting an awful lot of records continuously (e.g., 1,000s or 1,000,000s per hour - not 10 or 15 an hour).

Comment: @BIBD - Yes.  It's really generally only an issue when you have a RAC cluster, forcing the hot block to get sent over the network between different nodes constantly, and a very high volume of inserts.  Maybe the original developer was hoping that the system became way, way busier in the future :-)

Comment: There are also specific disadvantages to random keys of course: less efficient space usage due to 50:50 splits instead of 90:10, and the randomness causes more index blocks to be dirtied and thus more blocks need writing and logging. Maybe for long-running queries more blocks need to be inspected for consistency checking as well.

Comment: My conclusion... the original developer was re-inventing the wheel because they didn't know about sequences, GUID, and/or they once heard some myth about it being better for the PK to be random. Ripped and replaced with something sane.